# Program with threads for matrix multiplication

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix, concurrency, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to create a Java program with threads for matrix multiplication. This is the source code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MatrixTest {
    //Creating the matrix
    static int[][] mat = new int[3][3];
    static int[][] mat2 = new int[3][3];
    static int[][] result = new int[3][3];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creating the object of random class
        Random rand = new Random();

        //Filling first matrix with random values
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
                mat[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10);
            }
        }

        //Filling second matrix with random values
        for (int i = 0; i < mat2.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mat2[i].length; j++) {
                mat2[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10);
            }
        }

        try {
            //Object of multiply Class
            Multiply multiply = new Multiply(3, 3);

            //Threads
            MatrixMultiplier thread1 = new MatrixMultiplier(multiply);
            MatrixMultiplier thread2 = new MatrixMultiplier(multiply);
            MatrixMultiplier thread3 = new MatrixMultiplier(multiply);

            //Implementing threads
            Thread th1 = new Thread(thread1);
            Thread th2 = new Thread(thread2);
            Thread th3 = new Thread(thread3);

            //Starting threads
            th1.start();
            th2.start();
            th3.start();

            th1.join();
            th2.join();
            th3.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Printing the result
        System.out.println("\n\nResult:");
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(result[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }//End main
}//End Class

//Multiply Class
class Multiply extends MatrixTest {
    private int i;
    private int j;
    private int chance;

    public Multiply(int i, int j) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
        chance = 0;
    }

    //Matrix Multiplication Function
    public synchronized void multiplyMatrix() {
        int sum = 0;
        int a = 0;
        for (a = 0; a < i; a++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int b = 0; b < j; b++) {
                sum = sum + mat[chance][b] * mat2[b][a];
            }
            result[chance][a] = sum;
        }

        if (chance >= i)
            return;
        chance++;
    }
}//End multiply class

//Thread Class
class MatrixMultiplier implements Runnable {
    private final Multiply mul;

    public MatrixMultiplier(Multiply mul) {
        this.mul = mul;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mul.multiplyMatrix();
    }
}
```

I just tried on Eclipse and it works, but now I want to create another version of that program in which, I use one thread for each cell that I'll have on the result matrix. For example I've got two 3x3 matrices. So the result matrix will be 3x3. Then, I want to use 9 threads to calculate each one of the 9 cells of the result matrix.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm sure someone can help you! What are they helping you to achieve?

Comment: I need some help about sync of thread, because in that case i'm using only 3 thread. In the other program i want to use 9 or more thread (when i ll have matrix bigger than 3x3) one for each cells. I think that i need to create a cell class but at the moment i don't have other ideas

Comment: So are you looking for a way to create `n` threads where `n` is the number of cells there are?

Comment: So you want to create a thread to calculate a single cell of a matrix?  Break your program up so that it has a function call that can calculate a single cell, then invoke that from multiple threads as you did above for the whole matrix.  CAUTION do not expect this to run fast, threads are quite heavy weight and you will suffer from false sharing within the CPU caches.  The version that you already have is more concurrent than you may realise thanks to parallelism internal to a CPU and the increasing use of SIMD instructions from Hotspot.

Comment: Consider that is an excercice for prepare my exam :) Thanks for your cooperation :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create `n` Threads as follows (Note: `numberOfThreads` is the number of threads that you want to create. This will be the number of cells):

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>(numberOfThreads);

for (int x = 0; x < numberOfThreads; x++) {
   Thread t = new Thread(new MatrixMultiplier(multiply));
   t.start();
   threads.add(t);
}

for (Thread t : threads) {
   t.join();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the new Executor [framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to create Threads, instead of manually doing the plumbing.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreadsInPool);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
  Runnable worker = new Thread(new MatrixMultiplier(multiply));;
  executor.execute(worker);
}
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code i think that i resolve my problem. I don't use synchronized in the methods but i think that is not necessary in that case.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class MatrixProduct extends Thread {
    private int[][] A;
    private int[][] B;
    private int[][] C;
    private int rig, col;
    private int dim;

    public MatrixProduct(int[][] A, int[][] B, int[][] C, int rig, int col, int dim_com) {
        this.A = A;
        this.B = B;
        this.C = C;
        this.rig = rig;
        this.col = col;
        this.dim = dim_com;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            C[rig][col] += A[rig][i] * B[i][col];
        }
        System.out.println("Thread " + rig + "," + col + " complete.");
    }
}

public class MatrixMultiplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Row of Matrix A: ");
        int rA = In.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Column of Matrix A: ");
        int cA = In.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Row of Matrix B: ");
        int rB = In.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Column of Matrix B: ");
        int cB = In.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        if (cA != rB) {
            System.out.println("We can't do the matrix product!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        System.out.println("The matrix result from product will be " + rA + " x " + cB);
        System.out.println();
        int[][] A = new int[rA][cA];
        int[][] B = new int[rB][cB];
        int[][] C = new int[rA][cB];
        MatrixProduct[][] thrd = new MatrixProduct[rA][cB];

        System.out.println("Insert A:");
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < rA; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cA; j++) {
                System.out.print(i + "," + j + " = ");
                A[i][j] = In.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Insert B:");
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < rB; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cB; j++) {
                System.out.print(i + "," + j + " = ");
                B[i][j] = In.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < rA; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cB; j++) {
                thrd[i][j] = new MatrixProduct(A, B, C, i, j, cA);
                thrd[i][j].start();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rA; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cB; j++) {
                try {
                    thrd[i][j].join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Result");
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < rA; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cB; j++) {
                System.out.print(C[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider `Matrix.java` and `Main.java` as follows.

```java
public class Matrix extends Thread {
    private static int[][] a;
    private static int[][] b;
    private static int[][] c;

    /* You might need other variables as well */
    private int i;
    private int j;
    private int z1;

    private int s;
    private int k;

    public Matrix(int[][] A, final int[][] B, final int[][] C, int i, int j, int z1) { // need to change this, might
        // need some information
        a = A;
        b = B;
        c = C;
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
        this.z1 = z1; // a[0].length
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (c) {
            // 3. How to allocate work for each thread (recall it is the run function which
            // all the threads execute)

            // Here this code implements the allocated work for perticular thread
            // Each element of the resulting matrix will generate by a perticular thread
            for (s = 0, k = 0; k < z1; k++)
                s += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            c[i][j] = s;
        }
    }

    public static int[][] returnC() {
        return c;
    }

    public static int[][] multiply(final int[][] a, final int[][] b) {
        /*
         * check if multipication can be done, if not return null allocate required
         * memory return a * b
         */
        final int x = a.length;
        final int y = b[0].length;

        final int z1 = a[0].length;
        final int z2 = b.length;

        if (z1 != z2) {
            System.out.println("Cannnot multiply");
            return null;
        }

        final int[][] c = new int[x][y];
        int i, j;

        // 1. How to use threads to parallelize the operation?
        // Every element in the resulting matrix will be determined by a different
        // thread

        // 2. How may threads to use?
        // x * y threads are used to generate the result.
        for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                try {
                    Matrix temp_thread = new Matrix(a, b, c, i, j, z1);
                    temp_thread.start();

                    // 4. How to synchronize?

                    // synchronized() is used with join() to guarantee that the perticular thread
                    // will be accessed first
                    temp_thread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        return Matrix.returnC();
    }
}
```

You can use `Main.java` to give 2 matrices that need to be multiplied.

```java
class Main {
    public static int[][] a = {
            {1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1}};

    public static int[][] b = {
            {1},
            {1},
            {1}};

    public static void print_matrix(int[][] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] x = Matrix.multiply(a, b);
        print_matrix(x); // see if the multipication is correct
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, what you all need to do is,

1) Create n (no of cells in resultant matrix) threads. Assign their roles. (Ex: Consider M X N, where M and N are matrices. 'thread1' is responsible for the multiplication of M's row_1 elements with N's column_1 elements and storing the result. This is the value for the resultant matrix's cell_1.)

2) Start each thread's process. (by start() method)

3) Wait until all the threads finish their processes and store the resultant value of each cell. Because those processes should be finished before displaying the resultant matrix. (You can do this by join() methods, and other possibilities too)

4) Now, you can display the resultant matrix.

Note:

1) Since, in this example, the shared resources (M and N) are only used to read only purpose, you don't need to use 'synchronized' methods to access them.

2) You can see, in this program, there are a group of threads running and all of them needs to achieve a specific status by their own, before continuing the next step of the whole program. This multi-threaded programming model is known as a [Barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 0):

In my solution I assigned to each worker a number of rows `numRowForThread` equals to: (number of rows of `matA`) / (number of threads).

```java
public class MatMulConcur {
    private final static int NUM_OF_THREAD = 1;
    private static Mat matC;

    public static Mat matmul(Mat matA, Mat matB) {
        matC = new Mat(matA.getNRows(), matB.getNColumns());
        return mul(matA, matB);
    }

    private static Mat mul(Mat matA, Mat matB) {
        int numRowForThread;
        int numRowA = matA.getNRows();
        int startRow = 0;

        Worker[] myWorker = new Worker[NUM_OF_THREAD];

        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_OF_THREAD; j++) {
            if (j < NUM_OF_THREAD - 1) {
                numRowForThread = (numRowA / NUM_OF_THREAD);
            } else {
                numRowForThread = (numRowA / NUM_OF_THREAD) + (numRowA % NUM_OF_THREAD);
            }
            myWorker[j] = new Worker(startRow, startRow + numRowForThread, matA, matB);
            myWorker[j].start();
            startRow += numRowForThread;
        }

        for (Worker worker : myWorker) {
            try {
                worker.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
        return matC;
    }

    private static class Worker extends Thread {
        private int startRow, stopRow;
        private Mat matA, matB;

        public Worker(int startRow, int stopRow, Mat matA, Mat matB) {
            super();
            this.startRow = startRow;
            this.stopRow = stopRow;
            this.matA = matA;
            this.matB = matB;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = startRow; i < stopRow; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < matB.getNColumns(); j++) {
                    double sum = 0;
                    for (int k = 0; k < matA.getNColumns(); k++) {
                        sum += matA.get(i, k) * matB.get(k, j);
                    }
                    matC.set(i, j, sum);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where for the `class Mat`, I used this implementation:

```java
public class Mat {
    private double[][] mat;

    public Mat(int n, int m) {
        mat = new double[n][m];
    }

    public void set(int i, int j, double v) {
        mat[i][j] = v;
    }

    public double get(int i, int j) {
        return mat[i][j];
    }

    public int getNRows() {
        return mat.length;
    }

    public int getNColumns() {
        return mat[0].length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried below code in eclipse as per thread for each cell. It works fine, you can check it.

```java
class ResMatrix {
    static int[][] arrres = new int[2][2];
}

class Matrix {
    int[][] arr = new int[2][2];

    void setV(int v) {
        //int tmp = v;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = v;
                v = v + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    int[][] getV() {
        return arr;
    }
}

class Mul extends Thread {
    public int row;
    public int col;
    Matrix m;
    Matrix m1;

    Mul(int row, int col, Matrix m, Matrix m1) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        this.m = m;
        this.m1 = m1;
    }

    public void run() {
        //System.out.println("Started Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        int tmp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            tmp = tmp + this.m.getV()[row][i] * this.m1.getV()[i][col];
        }
        ResMatrix.arrres[row][col] = tmp;
        System.out.println("Started Thread END: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}

public class Test {
    //static int[][] arrres =new int[2][2];
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Matrix mm = new Matrix();
        mm.setV(1);
        Matrix mm1 = new Matrix();
        mm1.setV(2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                Mul mul = new Mul(i, j, mm, mm1);
                mul.start();
                // mul.join();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                System.out.println("VALUE: " + ResMatrix.arrres[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```